# Google Cloud Webapp to use a user uploaded file for processing

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, web-applications, docx, file-processing

I recently moved my project from heroku to google cloud.  It's written in flask and basically does some text summary (nothing fancy) of an uploaded .docx file. I was able to locally use files on heroku due to their ephemeral file system.

With google cloud, finding myself lost trying to use a file uploaded and running python functions on it.

The error I'm getting is:
with open(self.file, 'rb') as file:  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'http://storage.googleapis.com/...'

Edited the specifics out for now but when I open the link in a browser it brings up the download window.  I know the file gets there since I go to google cloud and everything is in the proper bucket.

Also is there a way to delete from the bucket immediately after python goes through the document?  Currently have the lifecycle set to a day but just need the data temporarily runover.

I'm sorry if these are silly questions.  Very new to this and trying to learn.

Thanks

Oh and here's the current code

```
gcs = storage.Client()
user_file = request.files['file']
local = secure_filename(user_file.filename)
blob = bucket.blob(local)
blob.upload_from_string(user_file.read(),content_type=user_file.content_type)
this_file = f"http://storage.googleapis.com/{CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET}/{local}"
```

then a function is supposed to open this_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returned a public_url to a file name to be processed and used

```
   def open_file(self):
    url = self.file
    file = BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)
    return docx.Document(file)
```

Comment: also made use of the /tmp/ folder for easier use.  Let's you use standard python methods.